Vue/Bootstrap Table Conditional Styling Rows with CSS Class
I am working on a Vue/Bootstrap project and trying to conditionally change the color of my rows in a b-table based on the values of the items in the table. I have had some success using the method suggested in this post. The example from that post can be found below:
<template>
  <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields" :tbody-tr-class="rowClass">
  </b-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [ ... ],
      fields: [ ... ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    // ...
    rowClass(item, type) {
      if (item && type === 'row') {
        if (item.released === true) {
          return 'text-success'
        } else {
          return 'text-secondary'
        } 
      } else {
        return null
      }
    }
  }
}
<script>

I've seen several examples like the one above, but in every example I've seen, the classes returned by rowClass (or equivalent) are always bootstrap styles (e.g. table-success, table-danger). Is there a way to return a CSS class instead or override the bootstrap classes so that I can use a custom color? Thanks!

Did you tried putting a class in a style tag in your .vue with higher specificity than Bootstrap's (use your browser devtools to verify that part)? Otherwise, overwrite it in the Bootstrap config yes, might be more clean from a CSS framework point of view because having a background color is quite an obvious default.

Thanks for responding! Your answer helped point me in the right direction. Posting my solution now.

By using the /deep/ keyword next to the CSS styles I was returning (defined in the .vue class), I was able to apply my CSS styles using the method used above. The problem was with the scoped keyword. The resulting code looks something like this:
<template>
  <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields" :tbody-tr-class="rowClass">
  </b-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [ ... ],
      fields: [ ... ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    // ...
    rowClass(item, type) {
      if (item && type === 'row') {
        if (item.released === true) {
          return 'css-class-1'
        } else {
          return 'css-class-2'
        } 
      } else {
        return null
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
/deep/ .css-class-1 {
    background-color: red;
}
   
/deep/ .css-class-2 {
    background-color: green;
}
</style>

